How to tag related equations with the same number, but with a suffix letter
I am reading a book were the numbering of equations follows the format (<section>.<eq number>) with an additional perk, namely that whenever it makes sense to gather a set of equations together without loosing the possibility of referring to them individually, each of these equations share the same number, but a different suffixed letter. Here is a sample of the book showing this:

I find this feature very useful, so I wonder how to implement it correctly. I thought of using the align environment with \intertext{}, but I have no idea how could I impose the format <section>.<eq#><letter>. Thank you in advance.

Insert \begin{subequations} before group of equation and \end{subequations} after it.

amsmath's subequations environment in combination with \numberwithin{equation}{section} should get you the desired numbering scheme.

Following the comments to my question, I found this and this other posts from SE helping me achieve this result. If one encloses the align environment inside a subequations (requiring the amsmath package), each equation inside shares the same number as the others, but has a specific letter appended to it. Moreover, the equation numbering is formatted with \numberwithin{equation}{<depth>}, included in the preamble. Finally, individual equations inside align can be individually referred using hyperref and including a \label{} in their own line. The result would be something like this:
\documentclass{article}
\includepackage{amsmath, hyperref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
\begin{equation}
    a = b
\end{equation}
\subsection{First inside first}
\begin{subequations}
    \label{label0}
    \begin{align}
        1+1 = 2 & \label{label1}\\
        \intertext{Some text between the equations.}
        1+1 \equiv 0 &\text{ (mod 2)}\label{label2}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
Some text referring to all equations \ref{label0}, and specifically to
\ref{label1} and \ref{label2}.
\end{document}

which leads to

Alternatively, in case one doesn't need an align environment, one could drop the use of \intertext{} and simply go for
\begin{subequations}\label{label0}
    \begin{equation}\label{label1}
        1+1=2
    \end{equation}
Some text between the equations.
    \begin{equation}\label{label2}
        1+1\equiv 0 \text{ (mod 2)}
    \end{equation}
\end{subequations}

